# I am getting password text field in appcelerator

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am getting problem with text field as password. I set text field property password `hint:true`. When text field lose blur (leaves text field) to another field. When i need to change the password text field previous value I lossed. Please can you help me.

Here is my code:

My .js File

```
var passwordTextField = Ti.UI.createTextField({
    hintText : 'Password',
    hintTextColor : '#959697',
    width : '80%',
    left : '5%',
    height : 40,
    top:'10%',
    passwordMask : true,
    tintColor :'black',
    color : 'green',
    returnKeyType : Ti.UI.RETURNKEY_DONE,
    autocapitalization :Titanium.UI.TEXT_AUTOCAPITALIZATION_NONE,
});

$.index.add(passwordTextField);
$.index.open();
```

My .xml file:

```
<Alloy>
    <Window class="container" backgroundColor="black">
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

Comment: You can add the TextField in XML too and set the properties in TSS. Can you describe your problem a bit more and tell us your platform and SDK version

Comment: What you mean is to say is, after you enter the password, go to another field and come back again to the password field, the content is getting removed? Also like @miga mentioned, the same can also be achieved from XML too